# Windows 7 failed to load because the system registry file is missing or corrupt

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have some problem with [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/370733/windows-xp-could-not-start-because-the-following-file-is-missing-or-corrupt-wi).

I'm using windows 7. I'm getting this error when trying to boot or re-installation windows 7 (using dvd ori windows 7) :

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix problem:

1. insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2. choose your language settings, and click next
3. click "repair your computer"

If yo do not have this disc, contact your administrator system administrator or computer manufacture for assistance.

file: \windows\system32\config\system
status: 0xc0000098
info : windows failed to load because the system registry file is missing or corrupt
```

And then restart boot repair disc windows 7. Try run `CHKDSK x: /f /r` via command prompt

```
The type of the file system us NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks

NOTE :

- before repair system : windows 7 too slowly
- after repair system : got the black screen with only a mouse pointer

Comment: Have you tried `/x` parameter to `chkdsk`?

Comment: @week : yes, but get same result.

Comment: Use last System Restore Point or you may try to backup original SOFTWARE registry hive and copy backup from location `c:\windows\system32\config\RegBack\SOFTWARE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing a clean windows 7 from your windows installation disk , this should solve your problem and will give a clean and cured PC with win7.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly that the file "`\Windows\system32\config\system`" file may be missing or corrupted. Windows already has a backup for this file.

And in your case your Windows is Windows 7.

All you need to do is to replace the backup file with the current one and restart like the following:

1. Stick in the Windows 7 CD, and boot off of it.
2. Open a command prompt in the recovery console.
3. Go to the file location (maybe Windows appears in `d` drive not `c`, because usually there is a 100 MB partition that may be invisible for booting) and type the following commands:

   ```
   cd c:\Windows\system32\config
   ren SYSTEM SYSTEM.BACKUP
   copy regback\SYSTEM SYSTEM
   ```
4. Reboot and remove the Windows CD.

Answer (score -2):

My problem:Windows failed to load because the system registry file is missing or corrupt. Status:Oxc000014C

```
Stick in the Windows 7 CD, and boot off of it.


cd c:\Windows\system32\config
ren SYSTEM SYSTEM.BACKUP
copy regback\SYSTEM SYSTEM
```

NOW REGISTRY ISSUE ITS RESOLVED .

```
Reboot and remove the Windows
```

Comment: Under "... remove the Windows" did you mean "... remove Windows 7 CD"?